# ActionController::UnknownFormat in in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I'm trying to use the Devise Gem. I try to create an account without being logged in. The model controller returns me this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxv2A.png)

I don't understand. What is causing this error? My project on github is https://github.com/linneudm/tesouraria-dm

The members_controller:

```
class MembersController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :set_member, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_member!

  # GET /members
  # GET /members.json
  def index
    @members = Member.all
  end

  # GET /members/1
  # GET /members/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /members/new
  def new
    new!
  end

  # GET /members/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /members
  # POST /members.json
  def create
    create!
    respond_with(@member, :location => nil)
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /members/1
  # PATCH/PUT /members/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.update(member_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @member }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /members/1
  # DELETE /members/1.json
  def destroy
    destroy! { members_url }
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_member
      @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:member => [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:dt_Admission, :situation, :function, :start_Managment])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def member_params
      params.require(:member).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :dt_Admission, :situation, :function, :start_Managment)
    end
end
```

The registrations_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?


  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)}
  end
end
```

The routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  as :member do
    resource :registration, only: [:edit, :update], :path => '/members'
  end
  resources :members, :only => [:new, :create]

  devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}

  resources :expenses
  resources :incomings
  resources :expenses
  resources :members
  get 'home/index'
  root to:'home#index'


  #post 'members' => 'members#create ', as: :create_member

end
```

_form.html.erb - registrations

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal member" }) do |f| %>

    <%= devise_error_messages!%>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%=f.error_span(:email) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control'%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:password) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control' %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:password_confirmation) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to "Log in", new_member_session_path, :class => 'btn btn-info' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When asking questions on here, please could you include the text of your error along with the content of your code (please read this help entry: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than just links. This helps not only people answering your question, but anyone in the future that looks at your question in case the links no longer function.

Comment: Ok, so sorry. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is `member.members`, rails is taking the `'.members'` as an extension, like .json or .xml, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: What should I change? The form? The URL is 'member.members' and not 'members.member' ?

Comment: how you are creating the link that goes to that route?

Comment: There is a controller that points to the SIGN UP Devise, ie without being logged in. The controller is "registrations". I'll post it on topic.

Comment: The form contains a URL and point to url: members_path (resource_name) (in routes is members#create). *EDITED

Comment: Looks that this problem happen to other people https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2667, like I told you before, the ".members" is the problem, I'm not sure why Devise is creating it, you can find several ways to handle this in the link, I hope this can help you.

Comment: I saw. I can not find the solution. I'll keep trying. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the output of rake routes please.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jB2tTyR.png
http://i.imgur.com/lj8Kb3j.png
I can't post the output in code :(

Comment: I changed the form to registration_path(resource_name). Returned an authentication error that I am not logged in.  If I remove the line "before_action" returns the error which I spoke earlier.

Comment: In your routes file, registration_path (GET and POST) doesn't take any parameter, http://postimg.org/image/4cc0n86pb/ , so you need to, or add that param in the route, or use the rout without the param "url: registration_path()"

Comment: To register and log in at the same time, I need add the parameter? If I remove the parameter, ask her to be logged in to perform the action. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just use your form in this way 
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal member" }) do |f| %>

Comment: Thats ok! Thank you very much, my friend!

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I didn't understand your problem until I see your code and test it, you have several problems over here, but this first one is related to the before_action you have in MembersController, as your routes post to this controller when you sing_up, so you can use this before_action :authenticate_member!, except: [:create] (and remove the "resource_name" from the form), after this you'll get an error b/c member does not have a field called encrypted_password, you need to check again the way you implemented devise.

Comment: No, brother. That's OK. I remove the "resource name" and add correct path in the form. My application is OK now, thank you very much. What you said is exactly what I needed to get done. I really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error shows because you don't request the the url as json or html.check your console to know in which format it hit the url.

Comment: I checked the console. It tries commit the DB, but returns this:
Started POST "/members.member" is 127.0.0.1 at 2/21/2016 15:50:21 -0300
Processing by MembersController#create as

and the error in action
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:28:in `create'

So sorry, i'm beginner.